# Monitoring visit sites via Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik

Tell me please. Can I monitor the sites visited by mikrotik. There is a router through which there are 10 members. Can I see the headlines of sites they visit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with Mikrotik itself.

You need to capture/stream the traffic (`/tools sniffer`) to another computer or appliance that will process it and give you these kinds of statistics.